# Form with list, RecyclerView in ScrollView or multiple ViewHolder in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm making a form where user can see uploaded files and add new ones, besides other general inputs.

As of now, I'm nesting a `LinearLayout` (for general part of the form) and a `RecyclerView` (for the uploaded list) inside `NestedScrollingView`, with `nestedScrollingEnabled=false` and layout_height=`wrap`_content in `RecyclerView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <EditText/> and a bunch of other inputs....

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/attachment_preview_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

     </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

However, I've read that doing that is not good because it RecyclerView will not recycle its view and renders everything instead. And from a test I tried, (set a log on onCreateViewHolder), it does renders everything. And I'm worried it will cause OOM because the users range from low-end devices (512MB RAM) to high-end (2MB+ RAM)

But, making the general part as another view in RecyclerView will be tricky, because when the view is recycled I probably will lose whatever data changed in the input, unless I set up on change listener and update the actual data with the changes.

I'm trying to get the best of both worlds, recycling views for the upload list (because it can easily go to tens/hundreds) while keeping it easy to maintain the general form data especially when navigating away from/return to the app.

So, is there a way to make this work with the two options? Or is there a better solution to this case?